# Approximating a natural function spiral with a finite series of straight lines and constant curvature circle segments

Tags: geometry, circles, approximation, matlab, python

I am in need of bending a wire to a spiral shape defined by

$$
r(\phi)=a + b\phi + c\phi^2+d\phi^3
$$

My bending machine is capable of bending circle segments with a **constant** radius $R$ and angle $\alpha=n\cdot \alpha_0$ and feeding straight wire with the length $l=n\cdot l_0$ where $n$ is an **integer** number and $\alpha_0,l_0$ are machine parameters.

Another constraint is that every **straight line needs to be tangent to the next circle segment** and that every circle segment needs to be followed by a straight segment, and vice versa.

Below is an image of a circle approximated by this method, but I am not sure how it would relate to a spiral path.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how I could generate a series of circle segments and straight lines that approximates my curve with above constraints (i.e. $n\in \mathbb{N}$) such that the area integral between the original curve and the approximate path is minimized?

Ideally I would want a matlab or python script that outputs LRA (or YBC) coordinate data which is what a typical bending machine takes. ( LRA stands for length, rotation, angle for every segment where rotation would be required for a 3D shape but is not used in this case.)

Comment: You should provide the equation of the curve, and explain in more detail what you mean by "approximate".

Comment: There are different forms of spirals: the main ones being the archimedean spirals (constant width) and the logarithmic spirals (the snail), There is also the Cornu spiral, etc., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral  You have to say which one.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thanks for the hint, I specified the curve, but I am not sure how I can explain in more detail what I mean by approximate, other than that I want to construct a series of circle segments and lines that adheres to above constraints while resulting in the closest path to the equation curve

Comment: In general, using arcs of circle will give you a closer approximation than using straight segments.

Comment: @David of course but I am constrained by n being an integer, i.e. I have a finite amount of segments available.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca even if the arcs are of a constant radius at all times and are constrained by the angle being a multiple of 1.8 degrees?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> It's actually important to specify what "closest" means. Particularly, are you seeking a polar graph such that the _maximum difference in radii_ as a function of angle is minimized, such that the _maximum difference in polar slopes_ is minimized, something else...? Also, how much does it matter if the practical solution is not mathematically optimal?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noted the radius must be the same for all arcs. No, in that case it's probably better to use straight segments. But it also depends on the details of the curve.

Comment: The fixed radius and the integer multiples of lengths constrain this so that there may be a best solution for a given starting and ending point and a given definition of "best" (e.g., root mean square, average absolute deviation, maximum absolute deviation). Actually computing the absolute best solution still seems like a nightmare. Maybe something where you decide how much maximum absolute deviation you will allow, and each time you approach it you put another bend in the wire followed by a straight segment aimed to cross the curve and approach the maximum deviation inside the curve.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am not sure if I understand what maximum difference in radii would mean for my constant radii constraint. If I must choose another constraint, I would say the approximation should be as continuous as possible, e.g. the straight segment needs to be tangent to the circle segment (which is actually an important feature of the bending machine, I shall add that to the original question)

Comment: @DavidK after drawing a picture of this (see original question) I don't think the straight line should be crossing the path at each curve. Playing with same slope conditions of the segments to the correlating phi at the center point of the segments and then minimizing the total path integral might be more helpful but I am not sure if that makes sense for nonlinear spiral shapes.

Comment: My apology: By "radius" I meant "in the sense of polar coordinates," i.e., we start with the polar graph $r = r(\phi)$ of a cubic polynomial of angle, and we view the machine-shaped wire as a polar graph $f = f(\phi)$ after a suitable rigid motion of the plane. The "maximum difference in radius" would be the maximum of $|r(\phi) - f(\phi)|$ as $\phi$ varies. (Similarly, the "maximum difference of polar slopes" would be the maximum of $|r'(\phi) - f'(\phi)|$.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thanks for the clarification, that makes sense. It probably does not make much of a difference in the end for the practical application, but intuitively I would say that the maximum difference in radii should be minimized. However, if another constraint is needed to solve the equation, we might add a requirement for keeping the maximum difference in radiii below a fixed number while minimizing the difference of polar slopes.

Comment: @DavidK maybe there is some merit behind looking for intersects but I am wondering if it could be optimized iteratively.

we call $f(n_\text{tot},i)$ A circle segment with the center placed perpendicular to the curve and such that $f(1,0) \geq r(\phi(1,0)$ where phi can be determined by $n,i$ serves as starting curve. Then a program increments $n$ until $f(n,0) \leq r(\phi(n,0)$. i.e. we intersect and we call that $n=n_0$. Now we draw a straight segment with the same slope until $f(n_1,1) \geq r(\phi(n_1,1)$ (i.e. another intersect) at which point we start another circle segment and so on.

Comment: sorry, $n_\text{tot}$ would be the total number of steps and $i$ the amount of segments to that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing the following script. Unfortunately, I did not get the chance to test it as my priorities shifted, and I did not figure out the springback and clearance compensations yet, but the bending commands look realistic for the spiral shape I generated for.

You can find the code and the files for my bender in my github repository https://github.com/michox/Wire-Bender/blob/main/generate_g_code.py

```
import sympy as smp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as scp
from scipy import optimize
from math import ceil, floor
# Variables
start_angle = 0
end_angle = 2 * np.pi
R_tool = 2  # radius of the bending tool
d_wire = 1  # diameter of the wire
R = 2  # R_tool + d_wire / 2
alpha_0 = (
    2 * np.pi / 200
)  # step angle in radiant. this is the value for most standard steppers with 1.8 deg
l_0 = (
    5.5 * alpha_0
)  # radius of the feeding tool multiplied with the minimum step angle of the stepper
n_min = ceil(l_0/alpha_0/R)

t, tau = smp.symbols("t, tau", nonnegative=True)
s = smp.symbols("s", nonnegative=True)
circle_start, circle_end, line_end = smp.symbols("circle_start,circle_end, line_end", nonnegative=True)

# Your functions
x_expr = R * t * smp.cos(t)
y_expr = R * t * smp.sin(t)
# Math

dtx_expr = x_expr.diff(t)
dty_expr = y_expr.diff(t)
ddtx_expr = dtx_expr.diff(t)
ddty_expr = dty_expr.diff(t)

x = smp.lambdify(t, x_expr, "numpy")
y = smp.lambdify(t, y_expr, "numpy")
dtx = smp.lambdify(t, dtx_expr, "numpy")
dty = smp.lambdify(t, dty_expr, "numpy")

curvature = (dtx_expr * ddty_expr - ddtx_expr * dty_expr) / (
    (dtx_expr**2 + dty_expr**2) ** (3 / 2)
)
curvature = curvature.simplify()

arc_length = smp.integrate(
    smp.sqrt(dtx_expr**2 + dty_expr**2), (tau, start_angle, t)
).simplify()
solution = smp.solve(smp.Eq(arc_length, s), t)
curvature_of_s_expr = curvature.subs(t, solution[0])

length: float = float(smp.N(
    arc_length.subs(t, end_angle)
 - arc_length.subs(t, start_angle)
))
n_max = ceil(length / l_0)

# calculate a general expression for the circle deviation as a function of the circle end point circle_end
circle_deviation = smp.integrate(curvature_of_s_expr - 1 / R, (s, circle_start, circle_end))
# turn the general expression into a numeric function
circle_deviation_f = smp.lambdify([circle_start, circle_end], circle_deviation, "scipy")
# calculate a general expression for the circle deviation as a function of the circle end point circle_end and the line end point line_end
line_deviation = smp.integrate(curvature_of_s_expr, (s, circle_end, line_end))
# turn the general expression into a numeric function
line_deviation_f = smp.lambdify([circle_end, line_end], line_deviation, "scipy")

# carry over any deviation of previous segments
carry_over_deviation = 0



def total_deviation(circle_start_f,circle_end_f, line_end_f):
    return (
        circle_deviation_f(circle_start_f, circle_end_f)
        + line_deviation_f(circle_end_f, line_end_f)
        + carry_over_deviation
    )


def has_root_constraint(circle_start_f, circle_end_f, line_end_f):
    # deviation for smallest possible line_end and deviation for largest possible line_end have different sign assuming there is only 1 root (decreasing curvature)
    # if the two results have a different sign, the function has a root. The constraint expects a value >0 if the constraint is fulfilled and <0 if not so we add a negative sign
    return - total_deviation(circle_start_f, circle_end_f, line_end_f) * total_deviation(circle_start_f, circle_end_f, length)
    


# start the calculation for circle_start=0
circle_start_f = 0


circle_end_p = np.linspace(0, length, n_max)
line_end_p = np.linspace(0, length, n_max)
def plot_deviation(circle_start_f):
    # calculate the total deviation for circle_start_f for all circle_end and line_end in circle_end_p and line_end_p
    total_deviation_p = np.vectorize(total_deviation)(circle_start_f, circle_end_p[:, np.newaxis], line_end_p)
    # plot the deviation as a surface over circle_end_p and line_end_p
    plt.figure()
    plt.title("deviation")
    plt.xlabel("circle_end")
    plt.ylabel("line_end")
    # surface plot
    plt.contourf(circle_end_p, line_end_p, total_deviation_p, 100)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
# Generate Segments
segments = [0] ## first segment start point is 0
circle_start_f=0
while circle_start_f < length:
    print("calculating first end point circle_end")
    
    circle_end_min_f = circle_start_f + n_min*R*alpha_0

    # find the circle end point for which the deviation is zero at the given circle_start   
    try: 
        circle_end_f = scp.optimize.root_scalar(
            lambda circle_end: circle_deviation_f(circle_start_f, circle_end)+carry_over_deviation,
            x0=circle_end_min_f,
            bracket=[circle_end_min_f, length-l_0], # boundaries for the arc end position
        ).root
    except ValueError:
        circle_end_f = circle_end_min_f
    # # round the end point to the nearest value that will be a multiple of the step angle R*alpha_0 to serve as starting point for the optimization
    circle_end_f = ceil(circle_end_f / alpha_0 / R) * alpha_0 * R

    # try different circle_end and find the shortest line_end where the total deviation will be 0
    def minimize_line_end(circle_end_f):
        # find the line end point line_end for which the total deviation of the arc and the line segment is zero
        try:
            return scp.optimize.root_scalar(
                lambda line_end_f: total_deviation(circle_start_f, circle_end_f, line_end_f),
                x0=circle_end_f + l_0, # initial guess
                bracket=[circle_end_f, length],
            ).root # returns the line end point line_end_f where the total deviation is minimized
        except ValueError:
            print("no root found")
            return length

    # find the circle end for which the total deviation is minimized
    circle_end_opt = scp.optimize.minimize(
        minimize_line_end, 
        circle_end_f, # initial guess
        constraints=({"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda circle_end : has_root_constraint(circle_start_f, circle_end,circle_end + l_0)}),
        bounds=scp.optimize.Bounds(circle_end_min_f, length, True),
    ).x[0]

    # find closest mechanically possible position circle_end for the end of the arc
    circle_end_opt = ceil(circle_end_opt / alpha_0 / R) * alpha_0 * R
    # calculate the optimal end point of the line segment line_end for the new circle_end
    line_end_opt = minimize_line_end(circle_end_opt)
    # round again
    line_end_opt = ceil(line_end_opt / l_0) * l_0

    # calculate any left over deviation resulting from mechanical limitations to consider in the next segments
    carry_over_deviation = total_deviation(circle_start_f, circle_end_opt,line_end_opt)
    # set the new start point
    circle_start_f = line_end_opt
    # add the new segments to the list of segments
    print("found new segments circle_end={}, line_end={}".format(circle_end_opt, line_end_opt))
    print("carry over deviation={}".format(carry_over_deviation))
    segments.extend([circle_end_opt, line_end_opt])
# Plotting

##### gcode generation ######   
## stepper is configured to do 200 steps per mm so that 1 mm corresponds to 1 rotation instead.
l_compensation = 1.0 # compensation factor for the length of the line segments
bend_init = 0.0 # bend angle to add to the beginning of every end to compensate for clearance in the bend tool
bend_factor = 1.0 # factor to multiply the bend angle with to compensate for spring back

def bend(n): 
    # 
    return "G91\nG0 X{:.3f}\nG0 X-{:.3f}\nG90\n".format(n*0.01,n*0.01)

def feed(n):
    return "G0 Y{:.3f}\n".format(n*0.01)

# open a new text file
file = open("bending-file.gcode", "w")
for i in range(1,len(segments)):
    if i%2 != 0:
        file.write(feed(int((segments[i]-segments[i-1])/l_0)))
        file.write(bend(int((segments[i]-segments[i-1])/R/alpha_0)))
    else:
        file.write(feed(int((segments[i]-segments[i-1])/l_0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Abstractly, we're given a regular parametrized plane curve—possibly a polar graph $r = f(\phi)$ for $a \leq \phi \leq b$, possibly a Cartesian path $(x(t), y(t))$ for $a \leq t \leq b$—and the goal is to approximate the image by a finite sequence of

1. Line segments of fixed length $\ell_{0}$ [sic],
2. Circle arcs of fixed radius $R$ and angular size $\alpha_{0}$ [sic].

Qualitatively, we have three types of curve atom (or two if an arc can bend only leftward), and we want to build a molecular chain whose shape approximates the target path.

An approximation scheme may be viewed as constructing a finite sequence of segments-and-arcs. Because successive atoms are tangent at their common endpoints (as stipulated in an edit), the position and orientation of any particular atom locks in most of the freedom: There is a two-parameter family of initial positions and a one-parameter family of initial angles; after that there are only finitely many choices in total.

For definiteness, I'll assume arcs can bend in two directions (left and right). One geometrically natural idea is to approximate the signed curvature of the target path. For a regular (non-vanishing velocity) Cartesian parametrization $(x(t), y(t))$ with $a \leq t \leq b$, the [signed curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization) is
$$
k(t) = \frac{x'(t)y''(t) - x''(t)y'(t)}{(x'(t)^{2} + y'(t)^{2})^{3/2}}.
$$
To use this, we need to normalize in terms of arc length. Define
$$
s = \sigma(t) = \int_{a}^{t} \sqrt{x'(\tau)^{2} + y'(\tau)^{2}}\, d\tau,
$$
let $t = \sigma^{-1}(s)$ denote the inverse functional relationship, and finally define the signed curvature as a function of arc length
$$
\kappa(s) = k(t) = k(\sigma^{-1}(s)).
$$
The function $k$ can generally be found analytically; the arc length parameter $s$ may involve a "non-elementary" integral, and in any case the functional inversion needed to write the path parameter $t = \sigma^{-1}(s)$ in terms of arc length generally can be found only numerically.

Those difficulties aside, our problem is fairly simple. Using the machine parameters in the question, we want to approximate the curvature function $\kappa$ of the target path with a piecewise-constant function whose values are either $0$ on intervals of length $\ell = n\ell_{0}$, or else $\pm 1/R$ on intervals of length $\alpha R = n\alpha_{0}R$. (If the machine can only bend wire to the left, discard the value $-1/R$ coming from bending to the right.) That in turn is a matter of iteratively inspecting the values of $\kappa$ along the "next prospective interval," choosing one of the three (or two) available values, and (not) bending the wire accordingly.

To carry out this scheme in practice (for "tame" target shapes in a practical sense), it suffices to

- Calculate the curvature function $k(t)$ for $a \leq t \leq b$;
- Calculate the arc length function $s = \sigma(t)$ for $a \leq t \leq b$, or numerically approximate at a resolution suitably finer that the machine's smallest parameters ($\ell_{0}$ and $\alpha_{0}R$);
- Numerically approximate the inverse function $t = \sigma^{-1}(s)$, and tabulate the resulting values of the arc length-normalized curvature $\kappa(s)$.

That leaves rather a lot of numerical and logical coding, but is mathematically well-founded and looks feasible to implement.

Comment: thanks so much for this detailed formulation, investigating in curvature space in an interesting idea, it should be relatively easy to code in sympy. Any ideas regarding how to select the intervals? I believe it will be most practical to minimize the maximum deviation, but I am not sure how that would translate to curvature space. Another way would be to find the ideal fit for every given arc-segment pair by finding the parameters where deviation is minimized but again, not sure how to to this in curvature space.

Comment: Also isn't the curvature of the circle $\frac{1}{R}$ not $\frac{1}{R^2}$ ?

Comment: My oops with the curvature; fixed. <> For selecting intervals, I'd try sampling $t$ at arc length intervals that divide both $\ell_{0}$ and $\alpha_{0}R$ (or divide both as nearly as feasible). That way, the subdivision points at which the values $k(t) = \kappa(s)$ are known include the points where the machine can physically effect a bend. For "tame" curves (in a practical sense) I expect we need the curvature sampled at about twice the frequency of the bend points, i.e., we'd like the curvature at equally-spaced $s$ values $A<B<A'$ in order to decide whether to bend at $A$ and $A'$.

Comment: IIRC, the rationales for approximating curvature include: 1. Curvature is the geometric parameter the bending machine directly controls; 2. The "fundamental theorem of plane curves" guarantees that the signed curvature function uniquely determines a curve up to rigid motion of the plane; 3. Maximum deviation depends not only on the shapes of the target curve and wire, but on their relative placement in the plane.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you showed us the spiral that you are trying to define with straight lines and circular arcs.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I implemented your approach for calculating the curvature in sympy and that calculated a closed solution curvature for a starting point of a=0 on a plain $r(\phi)=R_0\cdot \phi$ spiral, so I have the sampling for every point now. My spiral ultimately will be a 3rd degree polinomial in polar coordinates, however, I would like to keep it as general as possible for other applications, e.g. bending circles, squares or other shapes.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang one approach I am currently considering is to calculate the curvature difference integrals, i.e. $\int_{s_{n-1}}^{s_n} (\kappa(s) - 1/R) ds + \int_{s_{n}}^{s_{n+1}} \kappa(s) ds$ where the first integral is the integral between the difference in curvature between the arc and the target function and the second integral is over the line segment ans $s_n$ are the start/end points. Minimizing this integral should ensure that after every segment pair we get a close absolute placement.  The second constraint could be to minimize $s_{n+1} - s_{n-1}$ to ensure a fine resolution?

Comment: Not sure I understand the rationale for the integrands; is the idea to group consecutive circular arcs (on $[s_{n-1},s_n]$) and line segments (on $[s_n,s_{n+1}]$), and to choose how many of each to pick? If so, one prospective complication is that minimizing also depends on the "break point" $s_n$. In any case, I'm interested (as surely others are, too) to see how this all turns out in actual bent wire! Particularly, I'll upvote if you answer your own question with outcomes.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang As I understand it, the integrals would represent the total summed up deviation in curvature from the original position, no? calculating the total deviation as a function of arc length $s$ and finding where it (almost) disappears should bend the wire into a shape such that any bend that was not possible could be corrected manually without affecting the subsequent geometry of the curve as the bending has already been done, just maybe not in the right place? I am not sure if I am formulating it clearly. I should have a sympy script in a day or so and be able to plot the result

Comment: That interpretation makes sense, yes; I guess the question was more about deciding how to choose the values $s_n$ (which looks geometrically significant), and whether or not that's part of the algorithm. <> No need to clarify, though; will wait to see how your code looks.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang just an update, I finished the script and am getting realistic results but plotting it is more complicated than I thought. Once I find some time to do the actual bending to validate the procedure, I will report back